# How to use 3rd party npm moduls in typescript (Angular2)

Tags: angular, webkit

Is there any documentation or a step by step guide which describes how to do this?

I want to give an example: I tried to use the package [`simpl-schema`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-schema) in an angular app. I've created a new app:

```
ng new ng-ss-test
cd ng-ss-test
npm install --save simpl-schema
```

In the app.component.ts I added:

```
let SimpleSchema = require('simpl-schema').default;
```

Now I've got the error:

```
ERROR /app/app.component.ts (2,20): Cannot find name 'require'.)
```

So, I've declared require:

```
declare var require: any
```

OK, this is actually working. I'm able to write things like

```
const schema = new SimpleSchema({
```

but I think thats not the way to do it. I still got Warnings:

```
WARNING in ./~/handlebars/lib/index.js
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.
 @ ./~/message-box/dist/MessageBox.js 13:18-39
 @ ./~/simpl-schema/dist/SimpleSchema.js
 @ ./~/simpl-schema/dist/main.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

Of course I can create type information for simpl-schem by running

```
dts-gen -m simpl-schema
```

but I still need the `require` line, right? I'm wondering what is the right way to use a 3rd party npm module in angular.

Comment: Angular CLI has documentation on adding third party libs https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: OK, that gives me the same result as using `require`. The warning about `require.extensions` is from the `simpl-schema`module so it has to be fixed there. I'm wondering how webpack does know which files it has to import from the `node_modules/simpl-schema` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a definition typescript in order to use third party modules. Each module comes with a typescript d.ts file which defines the methods you can use in the library. This, however, does not have any included so you'll need either to write your own d.ts file or check DefinitelyTyped's repo here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Simply add the d.ts file to your project and you'll be able to use your libraries.